# How to use setText() with a string object in android

Tags: android, string, textview

In the code below, I am reacting to an activity return.  When I get the correct code and result, I want to put the result of "data" into an uneditable text view.  I have tried to set the text view directly to the intent data using the following code:

```
encodedText.setText(data.getData().toString());
```

However I get an exception error when I try to do this.  I then tried to do it the following way(See arrow):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == request_Code) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String encoded = data.getData().toString();
            TextView encodedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result); 
        encodedText.setText(encoded); <------
        }            
    }
}
```

I put a break point at the line the arrow points to in the code example, and it is this line the program has a problem with.  I have looked at the setText() function in the textView docs and I still am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Anyone see what I don't?

Comment: I think your `encodedText` is null it isn't found in the layout. Are you sure you have this `TextView` in your activity layout?

Comment: encodedText is pointing to "result' which is the name of the textview in the layout.

Comment: You need to post the stacktrace, otherwise it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Slukian, You were right.  I had the TextView in the activity layout, but it currently was not active as the activity this problem was referencing was not active.  I changed the view to the current layout that the user sees and it works now.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you setting the `Intent` in the `setResult(resultCode, intent)` method ? Maybe you should try putting extras into the intent before setting result and trying to read that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to set the text(`encodedText.setText(encoded);`) because your `TextView`  that you lookup with `findViewById()` is `null`. Check your layout so you do have this `TextView` in the layout and avoid the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I assume it's a String object in the first place you can just cast it.

`String encoded = (String) data.getData();`